# How to resolve conflicting patches based on branch master when merged to branch next

Tags: git, merge, patch, git-workflow

In trying to grasp the Git workflow from the manual page [`gitworkflows(7)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) built on top of the integration branches `master`, `maint`, `next` and `pu`. I don't understand how to resolve a merge conflict that might arise when for example the maintainer attempts to merge patches from different contributors into the branch `next`, if those patches are based off branch `master` and the maintainer has none of them promoted to `master` so far.

Does somebody know an answer to my question above?

Comment: Is this the branching pattern of a specific project? If so, what other rules apply there? Could the maintainer ask contributors to base their contributions on the `next` branch instead of on `master` and ask them to re-base them on an updated `next` in case of merge conflicts (or to merge with the updated `next` and resolve merge conflicts themselves)?

Comment: It's the branching pattern described in the manual page `gitworkflows(7)` and the one that seems to be practiced by the Git project itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually answered on the manual page itself, at the end of section [Merge workflow](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows/2.14.1#_merge_workflow):

> Occasionally, the maintainer may get merge conflicts when he tries to
>   pull changes from downstream.  **In this case, he can ask downstream to
>   do the merge and resolve the conflicts themselves** (perhaps they will
>   know better how to resolve them).  It is one of the rare cases where
>   downstream *should* merge from upstream.

(**strong emphasis** mine, *regular emphasis* theirs)